# Fill a text field based on a value generated by drop down box selection

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to fetch the related allowance price based on the values of selected employee. When i select an employee, the allowances types generated, but same price is echoed for each allowance type.

[image: allowance price is same in all text fields.]

I tried the below code, but can't find the error. Could you please help me to find the error in my code??

```
            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="control-label col-lg-4" for="advanceAmount">Allowances: </label>
              <div class="col-lg-3"> 

                  <?php 
                            for($i = 0; $i < count($b); $i++){
                                echo '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom" name="allowance_type" value="' . $b[$i] . '">';
                            }
                            ?>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3"> 

                            <?php 
                              $i = 0;                               
                              $s = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from allowances_payroll where allowance_name = '$b[$i]'");

                              $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s);

                                    for($i = 0; $i < count($b); $i++){
                                     echo '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom"  value="' . $r['allowance_amount'] . '">';  
                            }
                            ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

$b is explode allowance types from the database.

```
     if($result1){
        while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
            $empId = $record['emp_id'];
            $department = $record['dep_name'];
            $salary = $record['emp_basicSalary'];
            $designation = $record['emp_classification'];

            $allowance = $record['allowances_types'];
            $b = explode(" ,", $allowance);                 

        }
      }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping in the wrong place.
Change your code to:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($b); $i++){                             
  $s = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from allowances_payroll where allowance_name = '{$b[$i]}'");

  $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s);

    echo '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm margin-bottom"  value="' . $r['allowance_amount'] . '">';  
  }
}
```

Also note the { } around `$b[$i]` or you can concatenate like by the other two.